# Detect 'High contrast' is enabled in

Tags: css

How do you detect if a user has accessibility tools activated on their device?

We would like to have a different CSS that kicks in if the user has contrast settings on their device.

We are currently playing around with audioeye tool which is a good tool, but costly so if there is away we can create a CSS that will activate when a user has accessibility settings turned on that may help.

Comment: See [`prefers-contrast`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-contrast) and [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [-ms-high-contrast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_Media_Queries_for_Accessibility#high_contrast_mode) or [prefers-contrast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-contrast).

`-ms-high-contrast`

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  /* All high contrast styling rules */
}
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: black-on-white) {
  div { background-image: url('image-bw.png'); }
}
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: white-on-black) {
  div { background-image: url('image-wb.png'); }
}
```

`prefers-contrast`

```
@media (prefers-contrast: more) {
  .contrast {
    outline: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```

Note that `prefers-constrast` is experimental yet.